# How to get a sharepoint list column to be a dropdown menu for a tables column which after selecting will update another list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

[This is the column of the list which I want as the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Wjy.png)

[This is the table in which I want the column to view as a dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YShpn.png)
once I select the option in the dropdown from the table then the project column present in the other list should get updated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, you can do this by creating a `Lookup column`.

Please refer to this document to create `Lookup column`: [How to create a Lookup column in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-a-lookup-column-in-sharepoint/#:%7E:text=SharePoint%20Create%20Lookup%20Column%201%20Build%20the%20custom,4%20One%20to%20Many%20Lookups%20%28Optional%29%20See%20More.)

*Note: Microsoft is providing this information as a convenience to you. The sites are not controlled by Microsoft. Microsoft cannot make any representations regarding the quality, safety, or suitability of any software or information found there. Please make sure that you completely understand the risk before retrieving any suggestions from the above link.*

Answer (score 0):

**To show column as a dropdown**:

You can use lookup columns in SharePoint to show data in one list to another list as dropdown in list forms. Follow below documentation for more information.

**Documentation**: [Create list relationships by using lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

**To update column value on selection**:

It is not possible to update the value of column in parent list (from where you have referenced the lookup column) on dropdown selection automatically using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

So, you have to use the custom solution for this which will be based on how you developed the table on SharePoint page. If you have used SharePoint server and JavaScript, you can use SharePoint REST API to update the column values on dropdown selection.